# adb push command failing permission denied, Read only

Tags: android

Hello for Android developers,

I am working on a project to extract the pictures taken from the Android camera and display.

Let me be little descriptive: I have 2 points to be clarified:
1> whether the concept I am following is correct? and
2> If yes, the problem in the subtask related to adb needs to be solved.

Let me write the steps , which I am following: I am using the Android 2.2 emulator
My understanding is the android camera pictures will be saved to the DCIM folder of the
SD Card.

a> Since , the emulator doesn't have a SD card, I need to make one which I did using mksdcard

b> After, step a> , I had to copy some of the image files to the SD Card image, which I tried using adb push, but I got the access is denied, Read only. 
After thorough searching, and spending few hours, I could find a solution to make the SD   card image writeable, by mount and remount command, I could not get the usage of the   command, and there is no complete description and usage of the command.

c> Then , I use the MediaStore to extract the images and thereon display.

My questions are :

1. Is the sequence I am following to approach the solution is correct;
2. If yes, please how do I push the image files to the SD card image created. I want a   detail mount, remount adb command with description for the filepath.
3. If the approach itself is not correct, can I know how to go about for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you are using adb to copy/delete image files from sd card. Cant you connect the sd card to pc with say a usb connector, open the sd card in windows explorer and do the same?